# How to return value to function and access it via a variable

Tags: javascript, angular, return

I have a method in my service where i wish to return true or false according to value gotten and access the value in my component.

My service file:

```
checkProfile (user) {
    let p = {
      username: user,
      key: '00'
    }
    this.postMethod(p).subscribe(
      d => {
        return d['code'] == '000' ? true : false;
      }
    )
  }
```

my component where i wish to know the value of the above:

```
let a = myService.checkProfile(this.user);
```

How do i get the method to return true or false so that i may be able to access it via the variable `a`. Right now `a` is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

checkProfile should return an Observable, use map to transform the value to a boolean. Read more about it here https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html

```
   checkProfile(user):Observable<boolean> {
       let p = {
           username: user,
           key: '00'
       }
       return this.postMethod(p).pipe(map(d=>{
           return d['code'] == '000' ? true : false 
       }))
  }
```

and in the component

```
export class YourComponent{
    check$:Observable<boolean> // if you want it to subscribe multiple times

    constructor(private myService:MyService){
        this.check$: Observable<boolean> = myService.checkProfile(this.user); // if 
    you want it to subscribe multiple times
    }
    // the other approach, if you only want to subscribe here 
    someMethod(){

        this.myService.checkProfile(this.user).subscribe((check:boolean)=>{
            let a =check // here you have the value in ts.
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was thinking there was a more simpler way to return a value to a method just by using the `return` keyword

Answer (score -1):

You could turn checkProfile into a Promise so you can then use async/await in other function calls

```
async checkProfile (user) {
    let p = {
      username: user,
      key: '00'
    }
    const d = await this.postMethod(p).toPromise()
    return d['code'] == '000' ? true : false;
}
```

```
let a = await myService.checkProfile(this.user);
```

You will also want to mark your component function as async. In my opinion this is all a lot easier as you don't have to handle multiple subscriptions and remembering to unsubscribe.

Comment: I wouldn’t turn it into a promise, but if you do, simply use .toPromise()

Comment: but how to use `await` as i can only use it inside an assync function

Comment: yeah @chrispbacon that would be my preference too, but just wanted to show something with as little code modification as possible. Will update to be tidier

Comment: @emmanuel, if you add your component code I can comment on that, but otherwise yes just make the function async.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should return your postMethod

like this:

```
checkProfile (user) {
    let p = {
      username: user,
      key: '00'
    }
    return this.postMethod(p).subscribe(
      d => {
        return d['code'] == '000' ? true : false;
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Its now returning the subscribe function instead of `true` or `false` as expected